# Mystery Padding..?

Tags: html, css, padding, cellpadding

I recently designed and finished 2 newsletters; but when I went back to make a quick change (add a background color to the outside of the container) I realized that there is some mystery padding between the content and the background color, what I'm trying to accomplish is to get the background color right up against the edge of the main content. I've played around with the CSS quite a bit, but still haven't come up with a fix..

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FrYuZ/1/)**

Here's the full source of the newsletter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <title>The Cook's Nook</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Client-specific Styles */
            #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" button. */
            body{width:100% !important;} .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
            body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes. */

            /* Reset Styles */
            body{margin:0; padding:0;}
            img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
            table td{border-collapse:collapse;}
            #backgroundTable{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}

            /* Template Styles */

            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ STANDARD STYLING: COMMON PAGE ELEMENTS /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ */

            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section background color
            * @tip Set the background color for your email. You may want to choose one that matches your company's branding.
            * @theme page
            */
            body, #backgroundTable{
                 background-color:#7C1A27;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section email border
            * @tip Set the border for your email.
            */
            #templateContainer{
            }

            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section heading 1
            * @tip Set the styling for all first-level headings in your emails. These should be the largest of your headings.
            * @style heading 1
            */
            h1, .h1{
                color:#000000;
                display:block;
                font-family:Arial;
                font-size:12px;
                line-height:100%;
                margin-top:0;
                margin-right:0;
                margin-left:0;
                text-align:left;
                font-weight: normal;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section heading 2
            * @tip Set the styling for all second-level headings in your emails.
            * @style heading 2
            */
            h2, .h2{
                 color:#202020;
                display:block;
                 font-family:Arial;
                 font-size:30px;
                 font-weight:bold;
                 line-height:100%;
                margin-top:0;
                margin-right:0;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-left:0;
                 text-align:left;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section heading 3
            * @tip Set the styling for all third-level headings in your emails.
            * @style heading 3
            */
            h3, .h3{
                 color:#202020;
                display:block;
                 font-family:Arial;
                 font-size:26px;
                 font-weight:bold;
                 line-height:100%;
                margin-top:0;
                margin-right:0;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-left:0;
                 text-align:left;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section heading 4
            * @tip Set the styling for all fourth-level headings in your emails. These should be the smallest of your headings.
            * @style heading 4
            */
            h4, .h4{
                 color:#202020;
                display:block;
                 font-family:Arial;
                 font-size:16px;
                 font-weight:normal;
                 line-height:100%;
                margin-top:0;
                margin-right:0;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-left:0;
                 text-align:left;
            }

            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ STANDARD STYLING: HEADER /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ */

            /**
            * @tab Header
            * @section header style
            * @tip Set the background color and border for your email's header area.
            * @theme header
            */
            #templateHeader{
                 background-color:#FFFFFF;
                 border-bottom:0;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Header
            * @section header text
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's header text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
            */
            .headerContent{
                 color:#202020;
                 font-family:Arial;
                 font-size:34px;
                 font-weight:bold;
                 line-height:100%;
                 padding:0;
                 text-align:center;
                 vertical-align:middle;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Header
            * @section header link
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's header links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
            */
            .headerContent a:link, .headerContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .headerContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
                 color:#336699;
                 font-weight:normal;
                 text-decoration:underline;
            }

            #headerImage{
                height:auto;
                max-width:600px !important;
            }

            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ STANDARD STYLING: MAIN BODY /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ */

            /**
            * @tab Body
            * @section body style
            * @tip Set the background color for your email's body area.
            */
            #templateContainer, .bodyContent{
                 background-color:#FFFFFF;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Body
            * @section body text
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's main content text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
            * @theme main
            */
            .bodyContent div{
                 color:#505050;
                 font-family:Arial;
                 font-size:13px;
                 line-height:120%;
                 text-align:left;
                 margin-left: 10px
            }

            /**
            * @tab Body
            * @section body link
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's main content links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
            */
            .bodyContent div a:link, .bodyContent div a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .bodyContent div a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
                 color:#336699;
                 font-weight:normal;
                 text-decoration:underline;
            }

            .bodyContent img{
                display:inline;
                height:auto;
            }

            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ STANDARD STYLING: FOOTER /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ */

            /**
            * @tab Footer
            * @section footer style
            * @tip Set the background color and top border for your email's footer area.
            * @theme footer
            */
            #templateFooter{
                 background-color:#FFFFFF;
                 border-top:0;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Footer
            * @section footer text
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's footer text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
            * @theme footer
            */
            .footerContent div{
                 color:#707070;
                 font-family:Arial;
                 font-size:12px;
                 line-height:125%;
                 text-align:left;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Footer
            * @section footer link
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's footer links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
            */
            .footerContent div a:link, .footerContent div a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .footerContent div a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
                 color:#336699;
                 font-weight:normal;
                 text-decoration:underline;
            }

            .footerContent img{
                display:inline;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Footer
            * @section social bar style
            * @tip Set the background color and border for your email's footer social bar.
            * @theme footer
            */
            #social{
                 background-color:#FAFAFA;
                 border:0;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Footer
            * @section social bar style
            * @tip Set the background color and border for your email's footer social bar.
            */
            #social div{
                 text-align:center;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Footer
            * @section utility bar style
            * @tip Set the background color and border for your email's footer utility bar.
            * @theme footer
            */
            #utility{
                 background-color:#FFFFFF;
                 border:0;
            }

            /**
            * @tab Footer
            * @section utility bar style
            * @tip Set the background color and border for your email's footer utility bar.
            */
            #utility div{
                 text-align:center;
            }

            #monkeyRewards img{
                max-width:190px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
        <center>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="backgroundTable">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateContainer">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- // Begin Template Header \\ -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateHeader">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="headerContent">

                                                <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Header Image \\ -->
                                                <img src="images/header-bg.png" />
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/social-events.png" style="float:right;padding-right:25px;" /></a>
                                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheCooksNook?fref=ts"><img src="images/social-fb.png" style="float:right;padding-right:3px;" /></a>
                                                <!-- // End Module: Standard Header Image \\ -->
                                            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" style="float:left;padding-top:20px;padding-left:30px;" /></a>
                                            <br /><br /><div style="float:right;">
                                                    <h1 style="padding-right:25px;text-align:right;margin-top:30px;"><strong>Holiday Hours:</strong>&nbsp;Monday-Friday&nbsp;9am-8pm</h1>
                                                    <h1 style="padding-right:25px;text-align:right;">Saturday&nbsp;9am-5pm&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;Sunday&nbsp;1pm-5pm</h1>
                                                </div>

                                            </td>                                                                                       
                                        </tr>                                       
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // End Template Header \\ -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- // Begin Template Body \\ -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateBody">
                                        <tr>
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/butn-home.png" style="padding-top:15px;" /></a>
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/butn-about-us.png" /></a>
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/butn-in-store-coupons.png" /></a>
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/butn-photo-gallery.png" /></a>
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/butn-recipe-blog.png" /></a> 
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/butn-contact-us.png" /></a>
                                            <td valign="top" class="bodyContent">                                                                                
                                                <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Content \\ -->
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                                                            <div>
                                                                A few years back (1998), one of our employees baked and brought this coffee cake recipe to all of us at the store.  We have had numerous calls over the years from people who misplaced this recipe and wanted to see if they could still get it from us.
                                                                <br /><br />
                                                                <h4>Cindy's Coffee Cake</h4>
                                                                <img src="images/featured-image.png" style="float:left;margin-top:5px;"/>                                                                          
                                                                <span style="line-height:110%;">     
                                                                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull; 1 yellow cake mix<br />
                                                                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull; 1 cup sour cream<br />
                                                                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull; 3 eggs<br />
                                                                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull; 1 cup pecans<br />
                                                                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull; ¼ cup water<br />
                                                                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull; ¾ cup brown sugar<br />
                                                                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull; 1 teaspoon cinnamon<br />
                                                                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull; ¾ cup melted margarine<br />
                                                                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull; 1 ¼ cups graham cracker crumbs<br /><br />
                                                                </span>                                                                             


                                                                Grease and flour a 10-inch round cake pan.  In a large bowl, combine cracker crumbs, nuts, brown sugar, cinnamon and margarine.  Set aside.  In another bowl, pour cake mix, sour cream, water and eggs.  Mix at low speed until moist, then beat at high speed for two minutes.  Pour half the batter into pan.  Sprinkle half crumb mix on top, then repeat with batter and crumb mix.  Bake at 350 degrees for 30 – 40 minutes until done.  Cool upright for 10 – 15 minutes.  Invert on plate.  Cool.  Glaze with powdered sugar and milk.                                                            </div>
                                                                <div style="margin-top:25px;"><center>
                                                                <img src="images/coupon-1.png" style="" />
                                                                <img src="images/coupon-2.png"  style="padding-left:15px;"/></center>
                                                                </div>                                            
                                                                <div style="float:right;padding-right:30px;padding-top:20px;">
                                                                    <a href="#"><img src="images/butn-view-print-coupons.png" /></a>
                                                                </div>                   
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <!-- // End Module: Standard Content \\ -->

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // End Template Body \\ -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- // Begin Template Footer \\ -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateFooter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="footerContent">                                            
                                                <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Footer \\ -->
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2" valign="middle" id="utility"  style="padding-top:2px;">
                                                            <div>
                                                                <img src="images/footer-bg.png" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>                                                    
                                                </table>
                                                <!-- // End Module: Standard Footer \\ -->                                            
                                           </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // End Template Footer \\ -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which mail clients are you seeing this mystery padding?

Comment: Do you mean the 10px margin on the left of your container (.bodyContent div)?    Edit: In this case, I think a screengrab to explain what you're looking for would really help.

Comment: Posting [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525829/the-mystery-of-the-added-padding) isn't likely to get you a good answer. It will be flagged, closed, and, most probably, downvoted, so you will lose some reputation.

Comment: This isn't the same question, take a look at the code, you'll notice that the code is different. In the beginning of the question it states that there are 2 newsletters, this is the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me to avoid bad behaviour with table is to set "table-layout:fixed;" on the tables and to set the colums width with  elements.

Plus, i suppose you are using some kind of tools to convert your style tag into inline css. I'ld advise against it, this will generate a lot of unecessary code that will add weight to your e-mail.

Comment: I've been meaning to reorganize the code, it's more messy because I was doing some last minute adjustments and haven't cleaned it up like it's supposed to be. I'll definitely clean up the code and try your suggestion. And to help clarify, I'll post a screengrab, something I should've thought about @isotrope.